# Excel VBA Hide Rows based on cell color and if command says "Yes"

Tags: vba, excel, row, show-hide

I am trying to hide rows based on two criteria:

Criteria 1: If cell Q3 has value "yes" hide cells that comply by criteria 2

Criteria 2: If cells in column A are the color RGB (253, 233, 217), hide that entire row.

Essentially, I have a list of days that tracks a count of emails per day and I want to hide any weekends so they don't show up on the graph that shows the trend. I'm dumbing it down my superiors so all they have to do is click "Yes" or "no" from a drop down in cell Q3 to hide the weekend rows. The weekends are colored a light orange (the rgb code listed above). it is also important that if the cell Q3 states "no" then all of the rows are to unhide/remain unhidden. The code I have right now is:

```
Sub HideRows()
BeginRow = 1
EndRow = 1000
ChkCol = 1
ChkCommCol = 17

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
    If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCommCol).Value = "Yes" Then
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol) = RGB(253, 233, 217) Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Unhide = True
    End If
Next RowCnt

End Sub
```

If you need more information, let me know! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If your code isn't working, please describe any errors and where they occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this code in any module code pane:

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, chkCol As Long, chkCommCol As Long, rowCnt As Long

    beginRow = 1
    endRow = cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row '<--| set 'endRow' to column A last not empty cell row index
    chkCol = 1
    chkCommCol = 17

    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'unhides all rows. Subsequent code will hide relevant ones 

    If cells(3, chkCommCol).Value = "Yes" Then '<--| if Q3 value is "Yes"
        For rowCnt = beginRow To endRow '<--| loop through the "limit" rows indexes 
            With cells(rowCnt, chkCol) '<--| reference current cell to be cheked
                .EntireRow.Hidden = (.Interior.Color = RGB(253, 233, 217)) '<--| set its corresponding Row 'Hidden' property to True if currently referenced cell has wanted color
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

and place the following code in your relevant worksheet code pane:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$Q$3" Then HideRows '<--| if "Q3" cell has been changed then run 'HideRows' macro
End Sub
```

Comment: I would love to tell you if this code worked out; however, when I entered it into the module and pressed Run, it started but now it won't stop. VBE is constantly running and the excel book itself is constantly saying Calculate in the bottom left corner. I can't select or edit any cells while this is happening. I ran this while Q3 said "Yes" but I don't know if that caused this.

Comment: Sorry, I erroneously type `Worksheet_SelectionChange` instead of `Worksheet_Change()`. And missed a `.Row`. See edited code. let me know

Comment: No worries, I wanted to make sure that it wasn't something that I had some wrong. I added the changes and it still only hides one row and I still have to manually run the macro. Any ideas why this isn't changing when I changed the code?

Comment: you have to follow the "instructions" I gave you: the 2nd code must be put in your relevant worksheet code pane (not in a standard module) and have each changing of its Q3 cell trigger the macro. Step through your code to see it's really like that

Comment: Okay, I understand now and I pasted the code in the correct places. So, the code automatically runs whenever I change Q3; however, it still only hides the first colored row.

Comment: There are 21 non empty cells and its formatted as a table so I can constantly add new dates. I should clarify: There are 5 tables total, one for each district. But the color of the cells carries over so the whole row hiding formula will affect the other 5 districts along with the first district.

Comment: Hi! I am running this code and it works perfectly but I noticed that the page kind of spazzes out as it refreshes while searching for all of the weekends. Is there anyway to get it to hide all of the weekends in one fell swoop or is it required to go down through each row and glitch as it checks it?

Comment: You can add Application.ScreenUpdating=False at the beginning if the sub and Application.ScreenUpdating=True right before its end.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're missing a few `End If` statements throughout your code, I've edited your question with some indentation to help show where these are, try to indent in the future to help ensure you close off `Loops` and `If` statements.

With regards to your `If` statements, you need to check the cells' interiors for their colours as opposed to just the cells. This is done with the syntax:

```
Cells(x, y).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
```

Try this:

```
Sub HideRows()
BeginRow = 1
EndRow = 1000
ChkCol = 1
ChkCommCol = 17

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Speeds up subroutine
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

If Cells(3, ChkCommCol).Value = "Yes" Then 'This line checks that `Q3` is "Yes"
    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow 'This line loops through the rows and hides the weekends
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 233, 217) Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next RowCnt
Else
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False 'This line unhides all rows in the activesheet if `Q3` isn't "Yes"
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this advice, I will definitely work to keep my lines properly indented. I ran the code and unfortunately, nothing happened. I used the top portion (beginrow, endrow, etc.) from something I found online but I don't know if that is the proper notation for what I want to do. There are no bugs with the code, it just doesn't change anything in the excel sheet.

Comment: Okay, looking again there are a few issues, the cell you are actually checking for `Yes/No` is actually being incremented from `BeginRow` to `EndRow`. I'll edit the code now as I'm sure we can cut it down a bit anyway.

Comment: If `Q3` is `No` did you want all the weekends to be shown?

Comment: Yes, if Q3 says "no" I would like all weekends to show.

Comment: Edited now, just to confirm, the column you are checking the cell colour for is currently the value of `ChkCol` which is column A, is that correct?

Comment: So a few things I have questions about/need to change: When I run the macro, it hides the first row that has that RGB color; however, it stops after that and doesn't hide the rest. Also, I know that you can "refresh" a macro by clicking elsewhere. Can I include that so I don't have to manually run the macro everytime I change between "Yes" and "No"?